# Do most Muslims not acknowledge the beliefs of ISIS as a form of Islam?

Tags: sects, violence

In an interview I heard on CSPAN with Jessica Stern (I found the same point documented online in [this](http://www.bostonglobe.com/magazine/2015/03/19/harvard-lecturer-jessica-stern-roots-isis/96sUAdThoxewSOEEmMmjtM/story.html) article), she claims that most Muslims do not acknowledge ISIS as a form of Islam in the same way that most Christians do not acknowledge Identity Christianity as a form of Christianity.  In the CSPAN interview, the claim was made in the context of their violent practices, and in the linked article it is made in connection to their sexual enslavement of women.

Is that accurate?  Do most Muslims reject the beliefs of ISIS as a form of Islam?

Comment: This is my first time here and I am not so familiar with the tags here.  Someone could help me with retagging.

Comment: It is true that most Muslims do not accept some of the beliefs that ISIS has or some of the actions which they do. However, this does not mean that ISIS members are not Muslims. In any case, ISIS is not even a sect of Islam to begin with. It's just an organization. I'm not really sure if I understand your question.

Comment: @Erciyes My question is just whether or not the claim made by Jessica Stern is accurate.  I tagged it as sect because I don't know what else to tag it.  I am asking about the world Islamic view of the beliefs of the organization ISIS and whether that organization has a valid belief system within Islam.  Is there anything I should do to clarify that?

Comment: Well...ISIS claims to be sunni. There are four major schools of law in Sunni Islam (Hanafi, Maliki, Hanbali, Shaf'ee) and what ISIS is doing goes against them. So according to these schools ISIS is wrong...and most Sunnis belong to these schools so they do not support ISIS. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Erciyes I think so.

Comment: I'm closing this as off-topic: The question itself (Do most muslims...) is fine and objectively answerable, but all it's doing is attracting polemic/apologetic answers more interested in pushing Truth than in answering the *actual* question (see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22).

Comment: @yEz: just think logically. Is it really possible that you can get opinion of even majority of muslims about any issue? i mean there are billions of muslims in world. and how many use internet? it might be approximately around 40% or may be more ? but never 100%. so you might only get to know opinion of minority, but never majority. there is no such study/research/statistical analysis done in this case. So theoratically and practically,you can never know about her view to be even close to accuracy

Comment: @HamzaIslam I wasn't hoping for all Muslims of the world to show up here and take my survey. I was hoping for evidence of their general acceptance or rejection, such as statements made by major Islamic leaders representing significant portions of Islam.

Comment: @goldPseudo I respect your decision to do whatever you feel is best for your site, but wouldn't it make more sense to have a policy which removes the bad answers instead of closing valid questions?

Comment: Sure, but considering there've already been three answers posted, *all* of which would fall under "remove the bad answers", one of which is *positively upvoted*, the community would need to actually step up and enforce such a rule.  As it is, it's just making more work for diamond moderators to clean up and I see no reason to believe it will improve.  This site has a long history of users abusing the site as a soapbox for debate and apologetic (see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22) and political questions like this are very prone to it.

Comment: If you want to bring it up for discussion in meta, feel free; I for one would love to see questions like this attract proper answers, but that requires that the community as a whole get on-board, and the community as a whole just plain can't (or won't) handle it right now. I had already needed to process two flags on this one already (one answer deleted outright) before I even closed it.

Comment: This would fit better on Skeptics.SE